# Poster Image Play Button

Tags: javascript, iphone, html

I am having a problem with the play button on a poster image for videos on the iPhone 6 Plus.  Initially the poster image will have the play button, but after pressing play and then minimizing the video player the poster image no longer has the play button on it.  However, the play button will display on it if I press pause on the video and the minimize the video player.

Has anyone come across this issue? It seems odd that it is only occurring on the iPhone 6 Plus and no other iPhone.

Comment: Please post some code. That would help enourmously.

Comment: @MateHegedus Sorry I can not do that as it is work sensitive.  i know that makes this a lot harder for anyone to help.

Comment: @urnotsam Not just harder, impossible. Modify the code to where it doesn't contain anything directly related to your work but still exhibits the same problems.